# UILabel not showing up updated height?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, view, label

In IB, label height is 50.
I have added text to the label until it expands it's height size.
I tried checking label height, but it still shows 50.
For example:

```
print(label.bounds.size.height) //50
label.text = "Long text more than 200 chars"
print(label.bounds.size.height) // still shows 50.
```

How can i get updated label height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
label.numberOfLines = 0

print(label.bounds.size.height) //50

label.text = "Long text more than 200 chars"

label.sizeToFit()

print(label.bounds.size.height)
```

Comment: no luck- i tested your code in playground in two scenarios adding and removing sizeToFit()

Comment: What was the final height value?

Comment: It depends on the length of the text. It was 162.5 for me.

Comment: Is it still not working for you? Make sure to set `numberOfLines` to zero.